# Why won't my bootstrap javascript run locally?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

So I thought I'd give you my code to explain what my issue is..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Guide</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
 </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="modal.js"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

There it is. but for some reason, the bootstrap js script isn't running so when I click the button nothing is happening...

anybody able to give me a hand?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Are you using a Web server?

Comment: You mean you're running a local web server, right?

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that was implied lol

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using a protocol-relative URL for jQuery. You should be seeing errors in the browser's console.

Try changing:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

When you open a file locally in your browser (outside of a web server) most browser's will use the `file://` protocol, so `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` becomes `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` and odds are that you don't have jQuery that location.

Comment: just realised that, also wasn't using the correct bootstrap script